# Trying to escape values in an array to execute in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to escape the quotes/special characters before I insert them into the db instead on manually doing it since the arrays in really dealing with have about 100 - 150 values. Am i misapplying the mysql_real_escape_string() function?

```
$names  =  array(
"Intro",
"James Bond",
"M&M\'s",
"Who\'s Fault?",
"Started From Here,
"Don\'t Start",
"I\'m Still"
);

$i = 1;

foreach ($names as $inner_names => $value)
{
    mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    mysql_query("UPDATE MixtapeSongs 
                    SET SongName = '$value' 
                  WHERE MixtapeID = 524 AND 
                        TrackNumber = '$i'") 
    or die("Query could not be completed!");
    echo "#" . $i . " - " . $value . ".....was updated to the database!";
    $i++;
}
```

It seems like its a simple fix but I'm having trouble. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` returns the escaped version of the string - you need to assign that back to $value.

Comment: (1.) You should use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` functions, which are deprecated. [More information avalible here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php); (2.) format your code, please.

Comment: You're also missing a closing quote: `"Started From Here` should be `"Started From Here"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function returns the escaped string, not a pass by reference, so do this:

`$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);`